# Jstree - precheck checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm  using JsTree 1.0 and having trouble pre-checking checkboxes using the checkbox plugin.

Here's my full code:

```
 $(".tree").bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
                 $('.tree li.checked').each(function () {
                     $(this).prop("checked", true);
                })
            }).jstree({ 
                "core" : { "animation" : 0}, 
                "json_data" : {
                    "ajax" : {
                        "url" : "/admin/posts/get_taxonomy_tree",
                        "data" : function (n) { 
                            return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 }; 
                        }
                    },
                    "progressive_render" : true
                },
                "checkbox" : {
                    "real_checkboxes" : true,
                    "real_checkboxes_names" : function(n){
                        return [("term_taxonomy_id_" + (n[0].id || Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000))), 1]; 
                    }
                    },
                "themes" : {
                    "url"   :   "/assets/admin/js/jstree/themes/default/style.css",
                    "icons": false
                },
                "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "checkbox" ]
            }).delegate("a", "click", function (event, data) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

I've added the bind event for `loading.jstree`, but this isn't correct - doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thank you!

EDIT:

Solution is to add the class `jstree-checked`, this will by default pre-check the box

Comment: so all the checkboxes you want chekced originally have the class "checked" right?

Comment: I can apply that class, it's not currently returning that in the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add the "checked" class because it used to pre-check boxes on load =)

Comment: Sure why not... close enough :)

Answer (score 5):

Solution is to add the class 'jstree-checked', this will by default pre-check the box

Answer (score 1):

The following code may resolve your issue.

```
$('.tree').jstree("check_all");
```