# jstree with default cheked attribute and find node by mask

Tags: jstree

I recently integrated jstree into my site, but the problem is that, I have no idea how to give jstree node element checked attribute by default, something like [Jstree - precheck checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573859/jstree-precheck-checkboxes) is not my case. Something like `data-jstree='{"selected":true}'` is working but I don't want element to be just selected.
And one more thing, I could not find anywhere: is it possible to get all nodes id (even if they are not selected), or can I get node id by mask?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by "just selected", maybe if you share your data and config it will be easier to help you (as it all depends on how you instantiate the tree and what data format you are using).

Comment: it's tree-state:I can select and node will look like selected, but not checked

Comment: `$('#jstree_rubrics_div').jstree({
   checkbox : {
    whole_node : false,
             tie_selection: false
        },
        "types" : {
            "default" : {
              "icon" : "fa fa-folder"
            },
            "contact" : {
              "icon" : "fa fa-envelope"
            }
        },
        plugins : ["checkbox", "types"]
  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest [commit](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/commit/5632b6eb1eb3b5add674b5a1c84cb9b6fbddf7e5) fixes this and enables you to use this (I guess this is what you need):

```
<div id="jstree">
    <ul>
        <li data-jstree='{"selected":true}'>Root 1</li>
        <li data-jstree='{"state":{"checked":true}}'>Root 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can download the latest code from here: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/archive/master.zip

Comment: Thank you, as I understand you are developer of this plugin, anyway, could you pleasse answer my second question: is it possible to get all nodes id even if they are not selected/checked? And what about nodes id mask?

Comment: You can not get nodes ID by a mask, but I guess it is trivial to `.filter()` out nodes you do not need once you get an array of all IDs. To get an array of all IDs you can either use `get_json('#', {flat:true})` (which can be slow and will get you an array of all nodes) OR `$('#tree').jstree(true)._model.data` - it is an internal storage object - all its keys are node IDs (except for the special key `#`)